# Inserting a page into a .pdf causes the rest of the document to become all symbols

Tags: adobe-acrobat

I'm trying to add another page to an existing .pdf document but every time I try the rest of the document becomes corrupt, it shows all symbols.

Why is that, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that neither file is password protected, or tried another tool e.g. [PDFsplit](http://www.paologios.com/products/?type=bin), [finePrint](http://fineprint.com/pdf/) or [PDFsam](http://www.pdfsam.org/download/#.UQGGvkqssaU) ? To determine if the issue is with the file or your adobe install?